# How significant should edits be?

Tags: discussion, editing

When users with <2k reputation click to edit another post, a message appears instructing them to avoid trivial edits. (This is my memory of the message--I no longer see it as I just passed the 2k reputation threshold, above which one's edits are automatically approved.)

Should small edits be avoided? I do think that making small corrections can improve a post, particularly when fixing things like misspellings, bad grammar, missing punctuation, lack of `code formatting`, etc. But when there are only one or two such edits, are these things too trivial to warrant changing the original post?

Perhaps the answer is that this analysis applies differently to particular types of edits. For example, is it trivial to correct small "formatting preferences" but not trivial to correct small misspellings? Let's say someone edits another user's post. The changes include (1) adding `code formatting` to fingering numbers (e.g., `123241 321321`) and (2) adding **bold** formatting to a couple headers that appear in the post (e.g., changing EDIT to **EDIT**). Are these changes too trivial to approve because they're formatting related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is yes - please avoid trivial edits.  If there is a single spelling mistake is not worth touching. That said, if you see a mistake, please look for others, including formatting or grammar, and if you can fix a few things at the same time, please do.